# Sending emails with pure Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sendgrid

I have problems with sending emails with pure Ruby. Here is how my script looks like:

```
Mail.defaults do
  delivery_method(
    :smtp,
    address: 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    port: 587,
    user_name: 'sendgrid_username',
    password: 'sendgrid_password',
    authentication: :login,
    enable_starttls_auto: false,
    openssl_verify_mode:  "none"
  )
end

Mail.deliver do
  from     'Test Email'
  to       'user@example.com'
  subject  'Here is the image you wanted'
  body     "Test Email"
end
```

This script raise the following error:

```
/Users/mateuszurbanski/.rubies/ruby-2.7.2/lib/ruby/2.7.0/net/smtp.rb:975:in `check_auth_response': 535 Authentication failed: Bad username / password (Net::SMTPAuthenticationError)
```

I'm using credentials from one of my Ruby on Rails project and they are fine. Any ideas?

Comment: What does "pure Ruby" mean here?

Comment: If you're getting an authentication rejection then those credentials are clearly not fine. You must check them again, and see what logging you can get from SendGrid to diagnose it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sendgrid recently transitioned to api keys and will reject plain auth, see [details here](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/upgrade-your-authentication-method-to-api-keys/).
Your old credentials while still being valid may not be accepted.

Generate a new api key in sendgrid and use it in place of password. Username will be `apikey`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using your SendGrid username and password in this config, use the following,

```
user_name: 'apikey',
password: '<sendgrid_api_key>',
```

This works for me when defining the smtp settings for ActionMailer, so it should work here as well.